# Causal Impact Package in R is showing a positive increase in my data when it should be decreasing instead

Tags: r, time-series, bayesian, causalimpact

Ok, first off I've used this same data set to create different plots and had no issues. The problem I'm having now is trying to get the causal impact package to plot my data as decreasing, but instead, it's showing an increasing trend, which is incorrect.

First I loaded my packages.

```
## Packages

library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(CausalImpact)
```

Then I made sure my date variable looked good and added a year column to my df

```
raw_data$Date -> dates
ymd(dates) -> dates

raw_data$Year = NA
raw_data$Year <- year(dates)
```

Then I created my pre and post periods for the causal impact analysis

```
#Create a Date Variable
rdate <- seq(as.Date("2018-09-01"), by = "month", length.out = 34)

#Establish Pre/Post Periods
pre.period <- as.Date(c("2018-09-01", "2020-02-01"))
post.period <- as.Date(c("2020-03-01", "2021-06-01"))

#Combine DV and IVs for Analysis
comb <- zoo(cbind(raw_data$ADP), rdate)
```

When I plotted the data using ggplot2 there were no issues.

```
which(raw_data$Date == "2018-09-01")
which(raw_data$Date == "2021-06-01")

df <- raw_data[19:nrow(raw_data),]

df$rdate <- rdate

ggplot(data=df, mapping = aes(x=rdate,y=ADP)) + geom_line()
```

[image]

Then I ran the causal impact analysis

```
impact <- CausalImpact(comb, pre.period, post.period, model.args = list(niter = 10000, nseasons = 12, season.duration = 1))
```

But the problem happens when I try to plot my data after running the analysis. Instead of showing a similar trend when using ggplot2, instead it shows that my data is increasing (which it isn't). As you can see, the graph from ggplot2 is different from that in the original plot from the causal impact package when they should be identical.

```
plot(impact)
summary(impact)
impact$summary
summary(impact, "report")
```

[image]

I ran the exact same code and analysis with a larger timeframe from 2017-03-01 through 2021-06-01 and I didn't have issues and got these results.

Why I am running into issues if the main difference is the dates I've used? Is there a specification I need to make in the impact command for it to plot a downward trend? Or is [causalimpact] not able to plot and account for a decreasing trend? Up until this point, the analyses I've done have all been positive/increasing trends. The main issue is with trying to run these analyses when my results should be decreasing.

Any thoughts or advice on this?

[image]